# How to convert a column with object dtype to float in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column named 'height' and I want to convert the values into float. The default unit is in meter, but it has some values in incorrect format, or in inches. It looks like

```
        height
0          16
1           7
2           7
3         6 m
4        2.40
5        5'8"
6          3m
7         6,9
8       9;6;3
9     Unknown
10       4.66
11 Bilinmiyor
12     11' 4"

dtype: object
```

Basically, I need to convert values in inches/ft to meter unit, convert values like `Bilinmiyor` and `Unknown` to `NaN`, remove the unit specification like `m`  `m`, replace comma in the decimal numbers with `.`, and keep the largest number for value `9;6;3`. The final dtypes should be float or int.

I am new to python so I don't really know how to use advanced techniques so far. I was trying to achieve the task using

```
def to_num(a):
    try:
        return float(pd.to_numeric(a, errors = 'raise'))
    except ValueError:
        return a

df['height'] = to_num(df['height'])
```

but it didn't work. I was wondering if I should use iteration but it seems very complicated to iterate through all cells in this column, because the dataset has more than 2 million rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you mate, I had the same kind of problems. But thankfully this is not that hard

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'height': [16, 7, '6m', '2.4', '3,5', 'Asdf', '9;6;3']})
df['height'] = df['height'].astype(str)  # force type str
df['height'] = df['height'].str.replace('.', ',', regex=False)  # . -> ,
df['height'] = df['height'].str.replace('[A-Za-z]', '')  # remove all characters (regex)
df['height'] = df['height'].str.split(';').apply(max)  # pick largest value from 9;6;3
df['height'] = pd.to_numeric(df['height'], errors='coerce')  # force float
```

And you get

```
height
0   16.0
1   7.0
2   6.0
3   2.4
4   3.5
5   NaN
6   9.0
```

Now if you want to convert your feet to meters (I'm assuming default is meter), you'll need to add a level of complexion

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

def feet_to_m(s):
    if '\'' in s or "\"" in s:
        if '\'' in s:
            feet = float(s.split('\'')[0])
        else:
            feet = 0
        if '\"' in s:
            if '\'' in s:
                inch = float(s.split('\'')[1].split('\"')[0])
            else:
                inch = float(s.split('\"')[0])
        else:
            inch = 0
        return (feet*12 + inch) * 0.0254
    else:
        return s

df = pd.DataFrame({'height': [16, 7, '6m', '2.4', '3,5', 'Asdf', '9;6;3', "11' 4\"", "4'", "15\""]})
df['height'] = df['height'].astype(str)  # force type str
df['height'] = df['height'].str.replace(',', '.', regex=False)  # . -> ,
df['height'] = df['height'].str.replace('[A-Za-z]', '')  # remove all characters
df['height'] = df['height'].str.split(';').apply(max)  # pick largest value from 9;6;3
df['height'] = df['height'].apply(feet_to_m)
df['height'] = pd.to_numeric(df['height'], errors='coerce')  # force float
```

to get

```
height
0   16.0000
1   7.0000
2   6.0000
3   2.4000
4   3.5000
5   NaN
6   9.0000
7   3.4544
8   1.2192
9   0.3810
```

hope this helps